# Groups of varying levels

Tags: reporting-services

I have a set of data which needs to be grouped to multiple levels. For example:

```
Group 1
    Group 2
        Line 1   Aggregated data
        Line 2   Aggregated data
        Totals for Group 2
    Group 3
        Line 3   Aggregated data
        Line 4   Aggregated data
        Line 5   Aggregated data
        Totals for Group 3
    Line 6       Aggregated data
    Totals for Group 1
Group 4
    Line 7       Aggregated data
    Line 8       Aggregated data
    Totals for Group 4
```

As you can hopefully see, Group 1 is made up of two other groups, but also has a category (Line 6) that is directly contained in Group 1. The main reason for this sort of grouping is so that the various subtotals will show up at the right places within the report.

I created a similar report where all of the line items are two levels deep and that was easy enough. I'm having trouble with this report though because the level of the data varies. I've looked at hierarchical groups, but all of the examples that I found had hierarchies of identical items (typically Employee->Manager hierarchies where every level is an employee). In this case though the groups are simply containers with no actual data themselves, so hierarchies don't seem to work here.

I have access to the data and the code that returns it, so if there's a solution that involves returning the data in a certain way then I can probably do that.

The data tables currently look something like this:

```
Lines-<Accounts (Each line item is made up of data from multiple accounts)
Groups-<Lines (Each line item is contained in a group)
Groups-Groups (Each group might be contained in a parent group - which then might further be contained in another group)

AccountBalances
AccountCode    Month    Amount
00001          201701   100.00
00001          201702   150.00
00002          201701   110.00
....

Lines
LineName              GroupName
Agency Commission     Commissions
Direct Commission     Commissions
Sales                 Income

LineMapping
LineName                 AccountCode
Agency Commission        00001
Agency Commission        00002
Direct Commission        00003
Direct Commission        00004
Direct Commission        00005
....

Groups
GroupCode      ParentGroupCode
Income         NULL
Commissions    Income
Other Income   Income
Sales Expense  Expense
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is there more to what the data tables currently look like?

Comment: Heh... looks like the "<" character begins comments or something, so the rest of it was being hidden. I've set it as "code" so that it remains literal.

Comment: Have you tried just inserting a row outside the group from the smallest child group in your hierarchy? In your case, selecting the entire row where Lines are, right clicking, insert outside group?

Comment: I'm not sure what that gains me. I have a row outside of the Lines group in the tablix which has the "GroupName", but nothing is rolling up correctly or ordering correctly. I'd expect it to be similar to a tree structure, but that's not happening.